# regex to allow only once "&" and "-"

Tags: javascript

I was trying this regex `^[A-Za-z &-]+[A-Za-z]$`

This is allowing these strings:

1. `abc && abc`
2. `abc -- abc`
3. `abc &&-- abc`

I want to restrict it to allow only one `&` or `-` at a time, i.e., `abc & abc`.
It should allow both the `&` and `-`, but not together, i.e., `fruits- apple & orange`.

Comment: What have you tried ? How did it fail ? .. I recommend you to read how regex works. Good starting point is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

Comment: @Pratham  var b = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z &-]+[A-Za-z]$"), then b.test("abc & xyz"), it is showing true. b.test("abc &- xyz") it is showing true for this also

Answer (score 4):

## Simple Answer to Allow Only One of `&` and `-`

Just move the `&` and `-` out of the character class that has the `+` after it:

```
^[A-Za-z ]+[&-][A-Za-z ]+$
```

(I added a `+` at the end and added a space to the final group, because your examples allow spaces after the punctuation and for multiple letters at the end.)

A cleaner version is this, using the case-insensitive flag:

```
/^[a-z ]+[&-][a-z ]+$/i
```

## Answer to Allow Both, but Only One Time Each

You [edited your question pretty significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47343809/5) after I posted this, which changed the meaning entirely. To allow *both* `&` and `-` in the same string, but only one time each and not adjacent to each other, you have to get more creative, as in:

```
/^[a-z ]+([&-])[a-z ]+(?!\1)[&-][a-z ]+$/i
```

This allows a `&` or `-` (the `([&-])`) the first time, but only allows the one that hasn't been used the second time. We do this with a negative lookahead group: `(?!\1)[&-]`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/39lx0C/1/tests).

Comment: in this i can't use both the &-. in input if i use both &- showing false. 
eg: abc - qwe & zxc

Comment: The regexes in my answer allow exactly one `&` or exactly one `-`, not both. `abc - qwe & zxc` would not match either of the regexes in my answer. Is it possible you are confused about what the `-` is for in, for example, `a-z`?

Comment: a-z this means allow all lowercase letters. 

I want to allow both the & - but restrict to it only once

Comment: ^[A-Za-z &-]+[A-Za-z]$ in this it allows fruits- apple & orange futher it allows "&" and "-" for number of times. I just want allow both but only once

Comment: @NandiniS Your edits changed the question quite a bit. I've edited my answer to address your revised question.

Comment: regex("^(?!.*?[&-]{2}|.*?  )[a-z &-]+$") this one works properly

Comment: @NandiniS Have you actually tested that? It doesn’t do anything like what you actually requested. It would match a lot of strings you say you don’t want.